# Connect to Oracle DB using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to connect to our Oracle database using Visual Studio (VS) 2017 (i am not able to upgrade to the latest version due to company policy). So far, I have downloaded ODTwithODAC183 from this site: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdev-downloads.html

I have done the installation properly , after the installation, I opened VS, and clicked on Tools -> Connect to Database and chose Oracle Database

[image]

After pressing OK, I got this screen below and filled it up accordingly:

[image]

Next I clicked on test connection, and I received a message saying that the connection is successfully established, however, on the second screenshot, if you look under Data Connection at the left side, under tables -> Relational tables, it is completely empty and none of the tables from the database have loaded.

I was wondering if anyone could please help me figure out how I can view the tables from an Oracle database using Visual Studio 2017.

thank you!

Comment: my first guess would be that you are connecting as a user/owner who does not have any tables.  The tables you want are owned by some other user/owner.

Comment: Do you know how I can solve for that? I don't really understand

Comment: I'm not familiare with VS, but it looks like it is doing the same thing as SQL Developer.  When you connect as user FRED, you only see the tables that are owned by FRED.  In SQL Dev there is a 'other users' icon in the navigation tree, that allows you to see the objects of other users (_assuming FRED has been granted the necessary privileges_).  I see a 'users' icon, perhaps it does the same thing.

Comment: I see, thank you, under the users icon, I only see my username and nothing else. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: _"What would you suggest I do?"_   Now we appear to be getting into a question about Visual Studio interface. On that I have no relevant experience.

Comment: Of course we still come back to my basic assumption that you are connecting to oracle as a user that does not own any tables. Can you confirm that your uses does or does not own any tables?

Comment: That's correct, as a user I do not own the tables